Enabling Java JNDI LDAP connection to Active Directory using SSH through remote SSH tunnelling
Firstly, I would like to validate my idea for the PoC, specifically I would like to understand whether this can be possible or not and furthermore some pointers with regards to how it can be done would be great.
Here is what I actually want to achieve, with some details of structure:

I want to connect to Active Directory, using LDAP. Active Directory is within the private network of my organisation. Hence, direct connection to Active Directory LDAP from external network is not possible.
My java service is running on an EC2 instance on cloud and it wants to integrate with the Active Directory LDAP using JNDI API

Will I be able to achieve following using SSH concepts:

Since inbound connection to the private network is not possible, I would like to write an agent that will be executed on some machine in my private network.
This agent will initiate a SSH tunnel with the EC2 instance. This will be remote tunnelling ssh connection: ssh -f -N -T -R7777:localhost:22 <ec2 domain name/ ip address>
Now that ssh tunnel is created, from the EC2 instance I can connect to the Active Directory. I will create a dynamic ssh connection on EC2 instance using: ssh -f -N -D 7777 username@remote_host or may be: ssh -p 7777:ldapserver:389 user@otherhost
Now, using this how can I integrate my java code to connect to create the LdapContext normally using the JNDI API, for example like this: ldapContext = new InitialLdapContext(env , null);
How should I should I form the URL and int initial environment?

The problem is, before even starting, I am not able to clearly join the dots and hence I require help and guidance/ direction to solve the problem. (The agent can be java or a nodejs program that is responsible for remote tunnelling...)
Note: Another confusion I have is regarding the user details while forming the ssh connection and also, how I can make it password-less?
Also, what will be the LDAP URL and what all connection details need to be provided for creating one in this scenario?

This would be possible, but...

(The agent can be java or a nodejs program that is responsible for remote tunnelling...)

It doesn't sound like that's necessary. Whatever method you use to start your agent, you can already use to start the SSH client directly – ssh is your "agent".

what will be the LDAP URL and what all connection details need to be provided for creating one in this scenario?

The same generic "SSH tunnel" answer applies here. Your SSH tunnel was configured to listen on localhost:7777 on the SSH server side, so whatever protocol you use, the URL would have to specify localhost:7777 as the server.
I would not recommend this approach. For one, proper use of LDAP with Active Directory involves Kerberos (GSSAPI or GSS-SPNEGO), and that – much like TLS – expects the hostname in the URL to match the server's identity; localhost will not match. And if you don't use Kerberos, then you have to use TLS, which will have the same problem.
(A 'dynamic' tunnel would work better, if Java could be told to use a SOCKS proxy for all communications – which your SSH software will emulate – but I don't think that's an option in Java?)

That aside, I personally don't trust SSH clients to reliably run for long periods of time; they all tend to be designed more for "one shot" connections, and VPN software tends to do a better job in several ways. So I'd just recommend you set up a VPN connection instead.
VPNs are inherently bidirectional, unless deliberate config causes them to be otherwise – with something like WireGuard or OpenVPN, it's always possible to initiate the tunnel from within the network out to your server and then have the server reach back to you over the tunnel – and while they do take more effort to restrict where the server can reach back, it often ends up in a more robust setup.
(Not to mention, this is the sort of thing that should probably be run by your organization's network people or security people, and if they agree to it, then they'd probably much prefer having the mechanism be VPN-shaped because then they can manage it themselves…)
